# OpenLayers - error thrown when registering some proj4 projections

Tags: openlayers, proj4js

I try to register in OpenLayers 6.8.1 a custom projection from epsg.io.

The projection can be defined in proj4 successfully, but OpenLayers throws an undefined error during registration.

The code is the following:

```
let projCode = "EPSG:102581";
let proj_wkt = 'PROJCS["NTF_France_I_degrees",GEOGCS["GCS_NTF",DATUM["Nouvelle_Triangulation_Francaise",SPHEROID["Clarke_1880_IGN",6378249.2,293.46602]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_1SP"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",600000],PARAMETER["False_Northing",1200000],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",2.337229166666667],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",49.5],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.999877341],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",49.5],UNIT["Meter",1],AUTHORITY["EPSG","102581"]]';
proj4.defs(projCode, proj_wkt);
try {
    ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
}catch(e){
    console.log("ERROR THROWN");
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.message);
    console.log(ol.proj.get(projCode));
}
```

And the associated console output (no info on the error):

[image]

Any explanation on why proj4 accepts the projection but not OpenLayers?

Comment: You should describe projection with `proj.4` descriptor, not WKT. See https://epsg.io/102581

Comment: You shouldn't use `EPSG` as the authority, if the code isn't from the EPSG registry ~ https://epsg.org/home.html

Comment: Which version of proj4 are you using?  Support for epsg WKT format is a recent addition.  There is no error with version 2.7.2 and later.

Comment: @TomazicM and Mike thanks, you were right. I provided a WKT which is not supported with the version of proj4 I was using (2.7.0). Upgrading to 2.7.5 works since WKT is now supported. I was focusing on openlayers because the error appeared during proj registration, but the issue was with the proj4.defs call. Strangely, some projections used to work with 2.7.0 even if entered as WKT input.

Comment: There are several WKT formats in use.  The ESRI WKT format was supported  The format used by epsg.org was not.  Also the alias Lambert_Conformal_Conic_1SP was not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer based on @TomazicM and @Mike comments.

Versions of proj4 prior to to 2.7.2 do not handle correctly EPSG WKT format as input. The projection should be described using a proj.4 descriptor:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=49.5 +lat_0=49.5 +lon_0=2.337229166666667 +k_0=0.999877341 +x_0=600000 +y_0=1200000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356514.999904194 +units=m +no_defs
```

In order to continue to use a WKT description, the version of proj4 should be updated. The unmodified code was tested successfully with proj4.js version 2.7.5.